# Search and save data to database

Tags: vb.net

I am using vb.net with `OleDb` database.
Following is  my code, although i am to search database but not able to save after making changes.
It displays following error at `Command.ExecuteNonQuery` level :

> "OleDbException was unhandled, Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Src_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Src.Click
    Dim Connection1 As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Satyam\Documents\Database2.accdb;" & "Persist Security Info=False;" & "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" & "your pass" & ";")
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand

    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
    Try
        Connection1.Open()
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT *  from Table1 WHERE ID=" & IDtxt.Text & "", Connection1)

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If dr.Read Then
            Me.IDtxt.Text = dr("ID")
            Me.Hbtxt.Text = dr("Hb")
            Me.TCtxt.Text = dr("TC")
            Me.DCtxt.Text = dr("DC")

            dr.Close()
        Else
            MsgBox("No Record")
        End If
    Catch
    End Try
    Connection1.Close()
End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Connection1 As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Satyam\Documents\Database2.accdb;")
    Connection1.Open()
    Dim ID : ID = Me.IDtxt.Text
    Dim Hb : Hb = Me.Hbtxt.Text
    Dim TC : TC = Me.TCtxt.Text
    Dim DC : DC = Me.DCtxt.Text


    Dim command As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE Table1 SET Hb = '" & Hb & "',TC = '" & TC & "',DC = '" & DC & "' WHERE ID = '" & ID & "'", Connection1)
    Command.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Connection1.Close()


End Sub
```

Comment: of what type is ID in database? If it is integer, you shouldn't have wrapped ID with quotes as it will be considered string : `WHERE ID = " & ID`

Comment: You should be using parameters anyway.  Check this out: http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html.  Note that the value you assign needs to be the appropriate data type so, if your ID is a number, you need to convert the `Text` of the `TextBox` to a number, which you should be doing anyway.

Comment: what are the datatype of DB,TC and DC?

Answer (score 0):

use parameter in your code..like this..

```
Dim command As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE Table1 SET Hb = @hb,TC = @tc,DC = @DC WHERE ID = @id", Connection1)

Command.parameters.add(new sqlparameter("@hb",Hb))
Command.parameters.add(new sqlparameter("@tc",tc))
Command.parameters.add(new sqlparameter("@dc",dc))
Command.parameters.add(new sqlparameter("@id",id))
Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```